# Laravel and AngularJS existing email verification within resource

Tags: angularjs, laravel, angular-resource

I am trying to create a new user with AngularJS form and Laravel as backend, the functionality works as expected with exception to checking for users with existing email. Below is my Angular `Factory`, `Controller` function for `ngSubmit` and `Laravel` controller function for processing form inputs.

```
UsersFactory.createNewUser = function(formData) {
    return $resource('api/users/create');
}


// controller function to process form    
$scope.processCreateUser = function() {
    // Add the user via Factory provided route and close the dialog
    UsersFactory.createNewUser().save($scope.formData).$promise.then(function(res) {
        $scope.formLoading = true;
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.close();
        },1000);
    });
}
// Laravel Controller function
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $existingUser = User::where('email',$request->input('email'))->get();

    if(!empty($existingUser))
    {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'User Already Exist with the same email address.']);
    } else {
        // save user in model
    }
}
```

I cannot seem to display the error message in the front-end, the backend seems to be working fine.

Comment: Does the console display any errors? Is it actually firing anything?

Comment: @AndyHolmes the console seems to be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

It seems to be my Laravel Controller is messing up. After changing to code below, my code started working properly.

```
// controller function to process form    
$scope.processCreateUser = function() {
    // Add the user via Factory provided route and close the dialog
    UsersFactory.createNewUser().save($scope.formData).$promise.then(function(res) {
        if(res.error)
        {
          console.log("error exists");
        }
        $scope.formLoading = true;
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.close();
        },1000);
    });
}

// Laravel controller function
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $existingUser = User::where('email',$request->input('email'))->get();

    if(count($existingUser) > 0)
    {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'User Already Exist with the same email address.']);
    } else {
        // save user in model
    }
}
```

I needed to count the collection arrays returned from Laravel Eloquent instead of checking with **!empty** condition.Hope this helps for someone facing the same situation.